# PowerShell script to create multiple Azure AD Users

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Can someone help with the PowerShell script to create multiple Azure AD Users. And Each User Should have a unique password.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried below script:

```
$Usernames = @("Raghu", "Rajesh", "Ramu", "Kiran", "Karan")
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "********" -AsPlainText -Force

foreach ($username in $Usernames) {
    # Check if the user already exists
    $existingUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$username@yourdomain.com'"
    
    if ($existingUser -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "User $username already exists. Skipping creation."
        continue
    }

    # Define user properties
    $displayName = $username
    $userPrincipalName = "$username@yourdomain.com"

    # Create the user account
    $newUser = New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -Password $password

    if ($newUser -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "User $username created successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed to create user $username."
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong/not-working with the script you've posted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help with the PowerShell script to create multiple Azure AD Users. And Each User Should have a unique password.

Here is the update `PowerShell` script to create `Azure AD` user with **unique** password.

```
    $usersData = @(                      
        @{
            DisplayName = "User1"
            UserName = "user1@domain.com"
            PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
        },
        @{
            DisplayName = "User2"
            UserName = "user2@domain.com"
            PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
        },
        @{
            DisplayName = "User3"
            UserName = "user3@domain.com"
            PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
        }
    )
    
    foreach ($userData in $usersData) {  
        $displayName = $userData.DisplayName
        $userName = $userData.UserName
        $passwordProfile = $userData.PasswordProfile
        
        $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password for $displayName"
        $passwordProfile.Password = $password
    
        # Generate mailNickname from DisplayName
        $mailNickname = $displayName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")
        
        $user = New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userName -PasswordProfile $passwordProfile -MailNickname $mailNickname -AccountEnabled $true
         
        Write-Output "User '$displayName' with UPN '$userName' created successfully."
    }
```

Once the above script ran, `Azure AD` users got created with random passwords successfully.

[image]

**Azure AD** users created in portal.

[image]

Reference:  [Create a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1-create-a-user)